# Accessing nested values in JQ using path passed through command line

Tags: json, shell, path, jq

How or if is it possible to extract data from JSON structure specifying path as an argument to the command. I got this simple snippet taken from some larger script just for simplicity and have problems working it out:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA='{
        "level1": {
                "level2": {
                        "level3": {
                                "foo": "bar",
                                "bar": "baz",
                                "baz": "bar"
                        }
                }
        }

}'

field="level1.level2.level3"

# does not work
jq -r --arg f ${field} '.[$f] | to_entries | .[] | "\"" + .key + "\"=\"" + .value + "\""' <<< ${DATA}

# works
jq -r --arg f ${field} '.level1.level2.level3 | to_entries | .[] | "\"" + .key + "\"=\"" + .value + "\""' <<< ${DATA}

# also works                              
field2="level3"

jq -r --arg f ${field2} '.level1.level2 | .[$f] | to_entries | .[] | "\"" + .key + "\"=\"" + .value + "\""' <<< ${DATA}
```

Gives the following output:

```
user@astra:~/test$ ./jqtest 
jq: error (at <stdin>:12): null (null) has no keys
"foo"="bar"
"bar"="baz"
"baz"="bar"
"foo"="bar"
"bar"="baz"
"baz"="bar"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq seems picky about paths in input arguments.

One solution could be to provide the path as a json array, and then use `getpath` to convert that to a path:

```
field='["level1", "level2", "level3"]'
jq -r --argjson f "$field" 'getpath($f)' <<< ${DATA}
```

Or for your specific question:

```
field='["level1", "level2", "level3"]'

jq -r --argjson f "${field}" 'getpath($f) | to_entries | .[] | "\"" + .key + "\"=\"" + .value + "\""' <<< ${DATA}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case `.[$f]` means "return the value associated with the key named `level1.level2.level3`". See:

```
$ jq --arg f 'level1.level2.level3' '.[$f]' <<< '{ "level1.level2.level3": "foo" }'
"foo"
```

Unless any of the path components contain a dot, splitting `$f` by dots and using the result as argument to `getpath` should work.

```
getpath($f / ".")
```